# Cannot Load Scene in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to reload the scene when clicking on a button, but its telling me beside the scene name (not loaded) and here is my code:

[image]

```
public void winClick()
{
    WinGUI.SetActive(false);
    NextLevel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    GameStateManager.GameState = GameState.Playing;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("mainGame");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Open "File > Build Settings" and ensure the mainGame scene is present in the scene list.

As a side note, you can avoid manually passing the scene name when you want to reload a scene with the following:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the scene is present in the scene list and its not working! its telling me not loaded for unknown reason